# Neo4j Cypher query - index lookup of both start and end nodes

Tags: neo4j, geospatial, cypher

I'm trying to find nodes where a relationship exists between a person and location as well as filter that location within a certain bounding box.

I'm able to produce the results I need but the poor performance is becoming an issue:

In the example below I'm starting with a user and finding all locations that user or anyone that user knows (up to 3 relationships deep) has visited.

```
START 
    user = node:USER('username:"testuser"')
MATCH 
    user-[:KNOWS*0..3]->(users)<-[:VISITED]-place
RETURN 
    place;
```

The performance is fine (<200 ms).

Once I add in the spatial filter the execution time jumps to 10 seconds.

```
START 
    user = node:USER('username:"testuser"'),
    place = node:LOCATION("bbox:[-0.32487837,0.10114981,50.469185,52.508842]") 
MATCH 
    user-[:KNOWS*0..3]->(users)<-[:VISITED]-place
RETURN 
    place;
```

The spatial query itself returns very quickly (< 100 ms), it's only when you put both of these start conditions together that the query hits the brakes.

Is there a better way of structuring this query so it performs better?

Any advice for executing a query with both a spatial filter as well as other indexed conditions?

*Additional context:*
This is Neo4j 1.9.2 via the Web Console.
In the example above the number of users 0-3 levels from testuser is 16. The number of places in the universe is >1000. The number of places within the bounding box is 933. The final number of places in the result is 290. The nodes themselves are very small - only ID and spatial data. The entire graph database is about 7 MB in size.

*Updated with query plan*

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["users", "user", "  UNNAMED6", "place", "  UNNAMED5"], returnItemNames=["place"], _rows=2633, _db_hits=0)
==> PatternMatch(g="(user)-['  UNNAMED5']-(users)", _rows=2633, _db_hits=0)
==>   Nodes(name="user", _rows=13281, _db_hits=13281)
==>     TraversalMatcher(trail="(place)-[  UNNAMED6:VISITED WHERE true AND true]->(users)", _rows=13281, _db_hits=14214)
==>       ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
```

I rebuild the graph, tuned the memory, shut down all other running applications, moved it to a much faster server and got it down to 2 seconds. The data is going to grow by 2 significant digits in a production scenario however so this really needs to be in the 1/10 of a second space...

Comment: Please share the query plan. In the console tab, type 'profile <my_cypher_query>'.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've posted the query plan.

Comment: further info needed: 1) START user = node:USER('username:"testuser"') MATCH user-[:KNOWS*0..3]->(users) return count(users) and 2) START     place = node:LOCATION("bbox:[-0.32487837,0.10114981,50.469185,52.508842]") RETURN count(place)

Comment: 16 friends 0-3 traversals away. 933 locations within the bounding box. As I increase the number of user relationships the performance degrades dramatically. With 200 friends 0-3 traversals away the query takes 10 seconds.